# Data contract serialization for object array

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, svcutil.exe

I have following scenario and I'm unable to find a solution:

I have multiple data contract proxys that are generated through `svcutil.exe` tool. I'm trying to serialize instance of `object[]` containing data contract proxy instances. Tried following:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   var known = new List<Type>(){typeof(myDataContracClass), typeof(object[])};
   DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), known );
   ser.WriteObject(XmlWriter.Create(sb), obj);
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then using it by:

```
object[] arrayToSerialize = new object[] { someGuid, myDatacontractProxyInstance};
var serialized = Serialize(arrayToSerialize);
```

EDIT: (To futher describe my setup)

I have placed following data contract attributes:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mynamespace-uri")]
```

in the svcutil.exe's proxy generation I have declared namespace `/n:*,My.Custom.Namespace`, which causes generated proxies to have different namespace than the data contract class.

Offtopic: Why microsoft ended up with so difficult serialization components?

Comment: `DataContract` namespaces and generated C#.NET class namespaces are different things.

Comment: @Paciv, sure - I never said they are :)

Comment: And your problem is that you hold in your array objects from different generated proxies ?

Answer (score 2):

You give the DataContractSerializer hints by decoration your DataContractClass with [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx).

Try this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DataContractSerializerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ArrayOfObjectsTest()
    {
        var dataContracClass = new DataContractClass() 
            { 
               Objects = new object[] { "Johan", 1 } 
            };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(dataContracClass.GetType());

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            ser.WriteObject(xmlWriter,dataContracClass);
        }
        string s = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Below is a class with attributes specifying how the class shall be serialized.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataContractClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public object[] Objects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See my edit. Generated proxies have different namespace than the classes used to generate them - this seems to cause problems for the DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Why cant you have the same namespace in the DataContract class?